# can openxlsx writeData() write to multiple columns?

Tags: r, openxlsx

The following code creates an excel file with the letters a to f on different rows within the same column. Is there a way to have the letters in 3 columns and 2 rows while only using one writeData() function?

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, 1)
writeData(wb, 1, c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), startCol = 5, startRow = 5)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

So i would want it to output like this:

```
a b c
d e f
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are supplying a vector to the `writeData` function. That is why you have everything in 1 column. If you supply a matrix or a data.frame you would get the result you want. Below a simple example that does what you want.

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, 1)

writeData(wb, 1, 
          matrix(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), nrow = 2), # <-- matrix / data.frame
          colNames = FALSE, # <-- set colNames to false
          startCol = 5, 
          startRow = 5)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```